# Can these shoes be used to play football (soccer) on a regular basis (on a hard surface)

Tags: football, equipment

I have recently ordered a new pair of soccer boots (Nemeziz) and I was wondering if they are actually meant for soccer (on a hard surface like tarmac). They look more like casual boots.

[image: Nemeziz Tango 17.1 Trainers(TR)]

[image: Another image]

Also, these boots seem to weigh 300 grams. Do they feel light?

Comment: Why don't you go to the official product page on [Adidas](http://m.adidas.com/us/nemeziz-tango-17.1-shoes/BB3660.html) and ask it there? The users who bought it will be of more help than us.

Comment: [Adidas Nemeziz Tango 17.1 TR](http://www.rebelsport.com.au/Product/adidas-Nemeziz-Tango-17-1-TR-Men-s-Indoor-Soccer-Shoes/53398910) seems to be a indoor football shoes. Which looks simillar to your shoes, so it is atleast made for indoor football.

Answer (score 1):

Having played football/soccer my whole life on everything from turf, grass concrete, indoor futsal courts, etc, I would say that, **Yes**, you could get away playing with these on a hard surface (like tarmac) or even on turf.

That said, the heel seems a bit high for what other turf/indoor shoes I have seen. This does not bode well if one has weak ankles.

With all this in mind, I have never worn these shoes so it would probably best to test them out yourself in relation to see if their weight truly feels "light". Keep in mind that being lightweight does not make them objectively better.

Answer (score -2):

It seems to me, that the top front of the shoes is from textile, which is not good. It can tear down when kicking the ball.

Comment: I think this would be better left as a comment rather than a full answer. Either way, it's hard for a question like this to elicit good answers.